# fatal error occurred while trying to sysprep the machine windows 8.1

Tags: sysprep, windows-8.1

I try do sysprep in Windows 8.1. I have created unattend.xml

```
<settings pass="oobeSystem">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <InputLocale>en-US</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
        <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
        <UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
        <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
    </component>
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <OEMInformation>
            <Manufacturer>XYZ</Manufacturer>
            <SupportURL>http://www.XYZ.com</SupportURL>
        </OEMInformation>
        <OOBE>
            <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
            <NetworkLocation>Work</NetworkLocation>
            <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
        </OOBE>
        <UserAccounts>
            <AdministratorPassword>
                <Value>XXXXXXXXX</Value>
                <PlainText>false</PlainText>
            </AdministratorPassword>
            <LocalAccounts>
                <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                    <Password>
                        <Value>XXXXXXX</Value>
                        <PlainText>false</PlainText>
                    </Password>
                    <Description>Admin</Description>
                    <DisplayName>Admin</DisplayName>
                    <Group>Administrators</Group>
                    <Name>Admin</Name>
                </LocalAccount>
            </LocalAccounts>
        </UserAccounts>
        <WindowsFeatures>
            <ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>false</ShowWindowsMediaPlayer>
            <ShowMediaCenter>false</ShowMediaCenter>
        </WindowsFeatures>
        <RegisteredOrganization>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</RegisteredOrganization>
        <RegisteredOwner>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</RegisteredOwner>
        <TimeZone>Central European Standard Time</TimeZone>
        <ShowWindowsLive>false</ShowWindowsLive>
    </component>
</settings>
<settings pass="specialize">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <RegisteredOrganization>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</RegisteredOrganization>
        <RegisteredOwner>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</RegisteredOwner>
        <ProductKey>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ProductKey>
    </component>
</settings>
```

And then I run

> sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /shutdown

I see this error:

> fatal error occurred while trying to sysprep the machine

This is output of setuperr.log

> 2013-11-13 15:59:08, Error      [0x0f0073] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:Not running DLLs; either the machine is in an invalid state or we couldn't update the recorded state, dwRet = 0x1f
>   2013-11-13 15:59:08, Error      [0x0f00ae] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while processing sysprep cleanup external providers; hr = 0x8007001f
>   2013-11-13 16:02:46, Error                 SYSPRP Package Microsoft.WinJS.2.0.Preview_1.0.9431.0_neutral__8wekyb3d8bbwe was installed for a user, but not provisioned for all users. This package will not
>  >function properly in the sysprep image.
>   
>   2013-11-13 16:02:46, Error                 SYSPRP Failed to remove apps for the current user: 0x80073cf2.
>   
>   2013-11-13 16:02:46, Error                 SYSPRP Exit code of RemoveAllApps thread was 0x3cf2.
>   
>   2013-11-13 16:02:46, Error      [0x0f0082] SYSPRP ActionPlatform::LaunchModule: Failure occurred while executing 'SysprepGeneralize' from C:\Windows\System32\AppxSysprep.dll; dwRet = 0x3cf2
>   2013-11-13 16:02:46, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::ExecuteAction: Error in executing action; dwRet = 0x3cf2
>   2013-11-13 16:02:46, Error                 SYSPRP ActionPlatform::ExecuteActionList: Error in execute actions; dwRet = 0x3cf2
>   2013-11-13 16:02:46, Error                 SYSPRP SysprepSession::Execute: Error in executing actions from C:\Windows\System32\Sysprep\ActionFiles\Generalize.xml; dwRet = 0x3cf2
>   2013-11-13 16:02:46, Error                 SYSPRP RunPlatformActions:Failed while executing SysprepSession actions; dwRet = 0x3cf2
>   2013-11-13 16:02:46, Error      [0x0f0070] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:An error occurred while running registry sysprep DLLs, halting sysprep execution. dwRet = 0x3cf2
>   2013-11-13 16:02:46, Error      [0x0f00a8] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while processing sysprep generalize internal providers; hr = 0x80073cf2
>   2013-11-13 16:19:24, Error      [0x0f0073] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:Not running DLLs; either the machine is in an invalid state or we couldn't update the recorded state, dwRet = 0x1f
>   2013-11-13 16:19:24, Error      [0x0f00ae] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while processing sysprep cleanup external providers; hr = 0x8007001f
>   2013-11-13 16:22:01, Error      [0x0f0073] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:Not running DLLs; either the machine is in an invalid state or we couldn't update the recorded state, dwRet = 0x1f
>   2013-11-13 16:22:01, Error      [0x0f00ae] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while processing sysprep cleanup external providers; hr = 0x8007001f
>   2013-11-13 16:24:41, Error      [0x0f00a4] SYSPRP WinMain: Unable to parse command-line arguments to sysprep; GLE = 0x0
>   2013-11-13 16:25:15, Error      [0x0f0073] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:Not running DLLs; either the machine is in an invalid state or we couldn't update the recorded state, dwRet = 0x1f
>   2013-11-13 16:25:15, Error      [0x0f00ae] SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while processing sysprep cleanup external providers; hr = 0x8007001f
>   2013-11-13 16:26:35, Error      [0x0f0073] SYSPRP RunExternalDlls:Not running DLLs; either the machine is in an invalid state or we couldn't update the recorded state, dwRet = 0x1f
>   2013-11-13 16:26:35, Error                 SYSPRP WinMain:Hit failure while processing sysprep re-specialize internal providers; hr = 0x8007001f

Comment: Are you missing **/unattend:**

Comment: I correct this but I still have this error

Comment: Can you find your **setuperr.log** and post the contents for the time the error occurred?

Comment: Also, run **slmgr /dlv** and past the result too.

Comment: don't update the new buildin Store Apps, they break Sysprep in 8.1

Comment: Do you know which hotfix tor windows 8.1 responsible for update sysprep 3.14 to version 3.18 ?

Comment: I only have 1 sysprep.exe in 8.1 and this is the RTM version 6.3.9600.16384

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the [Windows System Image Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766347(v=ws.10).aspx) (WSIM) to create your unattend file? What you have posted is incomplete. You are missing two lines at the top that will look like this:

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”utf-8”?>
<unattend xmlns-“urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend”>
```

And the ending:

```
</unattend>
```

The WSIM tool adds these for you automatically when you create your unattend file with it. The WSIM is part of the [Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39982) (WADK) for Windows 7 or 8/8.1. WSIM also looks at the available settings in the image so that you can only add settings appropriate to that image, and it has built in validation that will help with errors and deprecated settings.

Hope this helps,